# Flash AS3 Snooker Game

Tags: actionscript-3

So, I'm absolutely useless at Flash and stupidly thought creating a Snooker game wouldn't be too difficult for a school Assignment. I grossly underestimated.

I'm trying to make the cueBall MovieClip move towards the point where the Mouse clicked on the Stage.

So far I have made the cueBall move to the point where the Mouse clicked, but I need it to keep going (unless obstructed).

I think I need to somehow calculate the angle between the cueBall MovieClip and the Mouse and then tell the MovieClip to start moving in that direction.

Suggestions? It's probably something simple, I bet...

Thanks in advance.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameSetup);

var VelocityX;
var VelocityY;

var speed = 1;

var shootCount = 0;

var mouseXPos;
var mouseYPos;

function gameSetup(e:Event) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameSetup);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, aim);
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shoot);
}

function aim(e:Event) {
    cueStick.x = cueBall.x;
    cueStick.y = cueBall.y;

    cueStick.rotation = (Math.atan2(mouseY-cueStick.y, mouseX-cueStick.x))*(180/Math.PI);

    if (mouseX > 25.5 && mouseX < 614.5) {
        aimBall.visible = true;
        aimBall.x = mouseX;
    } else if (mouseX < 25.5) {
        aimBall.x = 25.5;
    } else if (mouseX > 614.5) {
        aimBall.x = 614.5;
    }

    if (mouseY > 25.5 && mouseY < 294.5) {
        aimBall.visible = true;
        aimBall.y = mouseY;
    } else if (mouseY < 25.5) {
        aimBall.y = 25.5;
    } else if (mouseY > 294.5) {
        aimBall.y = 294.5;
    }

    if (mouseX > 0 && mouseX < 640 && mouseY > 0 && mouseY < 320) {
        Mouse.hide();
    } else {
        Mouse.show();
    }

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drawCue);
}

function drawCue(e:MouseEvent) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, aim);

    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, shotAnim);
}

function shotAnim(e:MouseEvent) {
    mouseXPos = mouseX;
    mouseYPos = mouseY;
    cueStick.rotation = (Math.atan2(mouseYPos-cueStick.y, mouseXPos-cueStick.x))*(180/Math.PI);

    VelocityX = Math.cos(mouseX-cueBall.x) * speed;
    VelocityY = Math.sin(mouseY-cueBall.y) * speed;

    cueStick.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function shoot(e:Event) {
    if (shootCount == 1) {
        cueBall.x += VelocityX;
        cueBall.y += VelocityY;
        trace(VelocityX);
        trace(VelocityY);
        cueStick.visible = false;
    } else {
        cueStick.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need a physics engine like Box2DFlash: http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/

Comment: Yeah, I think you should pick something without physics.

Comment: Thanks, @Bolu. I'll have a look into Box2DFlash.

Comment: Unfortunately, @gladoscc, I've already submitted some previous assignments based on the planning for this game. From what I had seen in the planning, I didn't think the implementation of this would be too difficult. As I said, I underestimated. Now I'm just trying to my hardest to make the most of it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example is helpful to you:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/01/05/complete-flash-pool-game-with-highscores/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, you already have it setup so that when the mouse is clicked, the ball teleports to the mouse's location.

What you want is for the ball to move to the mouse's position over a period of time.

To do this, you will use something called an EnterFrame event. EnterFrame calls a function every frame, which you need to get the ball smoothly rolling to the mouse.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(event:Event) {
    // move the ball a little bit toward the mouse
}
```

Then, you need to determine in what direction the ball needs to roll. You will do this with trigonometric functions. In your OnClick handler, write something like:

```
VelocityX = Math.cos(mouse.x-ball.x) * SPEED;
VelocityY = Math.sin(mouse.y-ball.y) * SPEED;
```

Then, each frame, move the ball by that amount.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
function update(event:Event) {
    ball.x += VelocityX;
    ball.y += VelocityY;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I believe this is the right approach, it certainly makes sense to me. However, whenever I 'shoot' the ball, it heads of in a seemingly random direction. I'll update the main question with the code I currently have running. Maybe I've missed something...